# VBA JSON String

Tags: json, vba, ms-word

I have a Word VBA Macro in which I the requestbody of a httpRequest is a JSON string.:-

```
' Compose the request body
    Dim requestBody As String
    requestBody = {"message":{"subject":" & subject & ","body": {"content": " & body & ","contentType": "Text"},"toRecipients": {"emailAddress": {"address": " & recipient & "}}}}
```

When I compile I get a syntax error for the requestBody line.
No doubt I need to define it as a JSON string, but I cannot find out how!
It is a valid JSON string, I spent quite some time with JSON-Lint cleaning it up!

I have spent 2 days trying to find a solution.

Any pointers?
Thanking you

Comment: it would help to show the expected result
But anyway  a string in vba is like "...
But show your code with the subject etc... and we can help

Comment: Try `requestBody = "{""message"":{""subject"":"" & subject & "",""body"": {""content"": "" & body & "",""contentType"": ""Text""},""toRecipients"": {""emailAddress"": {""address"": "" & recipient & ""}}}}"`

Comment: @Red Hare I put the relevant code segment in the question.

Comment: @taller Thanks for that. It resolved the current issue. As a matter of interest I spent time getting rid of the double quotes as JSONLINT was telling me that it was not valid JSON! Ho Hum, that has educated me a bit.

Answer (score 2):

VBA strings are enclosed in double-quotes and any double-quotes inside a VBA string are escaped by using two consecutive double quotes.

So

> Hi "there"

becomes:

```
Dim s as String
s = "Hi ""there"""
```

In you case the string should be

```
requestBody = "{""message"":{""subject"":""" & subject & """,""body"": {""content"": """ & body & """,""contentType"": ""Text""},""toRecipients"": {""emailAddress"": {""address"": """ & recipient & """}}}}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have responded to @taller for the same information.